# Difficulty understanding loading strategies in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Posted this on reddit, though it might be more of a Stack Overflow question since I'm looking for an **example**.

I'm working on trying to get a good/more advanced grasp of SQLAlchemy, and I'm really struggling with the concept of eager/join loading, select loading, and subquery loading. Especially when to use each.
I've always tried to learn and apply the mantra of 'ask the DB for what you need in the most complete way possible with the fewest trips to avoid excess latency,' which is why I find this subject important. Mike Bayer, bless him, gives a shot explaining what to use when in the section of

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#what-kind-of-loading-to-use

but I find it incredibly difficult to understand it in a more 'plain english' way. In videos where he talks about or introduces the subject, he seems to advocate using a lot of joined eager loading. I have also read the section on the zen of eager loading; I understand the that the loading strategy can be fluid and change later as you're working with whatever data set and the results of the query will not change.

Specifically to the docs above, I get really confused on the One to Many joined/subquery parts, as well as the latter half of the Many to One join. Are there any easier to follow examples or code you guys have knowledge of that will help me better understand what strategy to use, when?

edit: Question is still kinda vague, I narrowed it down to these:

a) "However, the total number of rows fetched will be equal to the sum of the size of all the collections, plus one extra row for each parent object that has an empty collection."

That's a result of the left outer join giving blank columns, correct? Which in subquery loading, that doesn't happen because it matches both sides, due to innerjoin?

b) "If you know that each parent definitely has a child (i.e. the foreign key reference is NOT NULL), the joined load can be configured with innerjoin set to True, which is usually specified within the relationship(). For a load of objects where there are many possible target references which may have not been loaded already, joined loading with an INNER JOIN is extremely efficient."

Meaning that use innerjoin in cases where they will always match, otherwise just let left outer join do it's job and return the 100 objects?

c) "except perhaps that subquery loading can use an INNER JOIN in all cases whereas joined loading requires that the foreign key is NOT NULL."

Probably the one that confuses me the most, didn't the previous paragraph say that joined loading works by returning all 100 rows, regardless of foreign key? Why NOT NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of raylu at reddit:

a) Yes.

b) Yes. I'm not exactly sure why the INNER JOIN would be more efficient. Perhaps the efficiency gain only applies when compared against having many of the joined objects loaded in the session already. In that case, a LEFT OUTER JOIN would have to do the same number of loads. Perhaps "target references" refers to things on the "one" side of the relationship and loading useless NULL rows in a LEFT OUTER JOIN is the inefficiency.

c) "joined loading requires that the foreign key is NOT NULL [to use an INNER JOIN]."